# How is “The Stars My Destination” a grammatically correct title/sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, sentence-patterns, ellipses

It's a bit of a niche question, but I've always wondered how the title of Alfred Bester's 1956 novel is at all grammatically correct. I feel like it teeters on being grammatically sufficient, but isn't quite there yet.

Although, clearly, it seems to be considered grammatically correct (it's a fully published novel). Gleaning from prior knowledge, I think its "correctness" has to do with a removal (or insertion) of a simple verb, so to speak. So, here:

> "The Stars **Are** My Destination"; "The Stars **Be** My Destination".

Or, interestingly, now that I think about it:

> "The Stars **Betray** My Destination"; "The Stars **Forestall** My
> Destination".

Inserting a verb between 'Stars' and 'My' yields the correct sentence I would expect to read. Realistically, even a comma would suffice. And this rule can be applied to other sentences of the same structure:

> "My Corner Their Terrain," "The World Her Home," "Thou Cradle Myne
> Inheritance," etc.

Would this be considered a case of acceptable omission, or parallelism? Any help in understanding this definitively would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, note that book titles need not be (and usually aren't) complete sentences. Second, note that titles of any sort, like headlines, poems, and advertising slogans, do not follow the same grammatical rules as printed sentences. Third, read tchrist's response, which explains where the title came from.

Comment: *"clearly, it seems to be considered grammatically correct (it's a fully published novel)."* - Publishing doesn't guarantee correctness.

Comment: Is *Too Late the Phalarope* grammatical? *And Strange at Ecbatan the Trees?*

Comment: There's also 'The World My Oyster ... thank you Pan Am!' by Zan (Owen) Ward. Though 'The my World Oyster' is a string one would find it hard to justify 'grammatically', grammar doesn't apply too well to sub-independent clause strings. And of course 'I saw a coded message on the ticket: it read "The my World Oyster" ' means that _anything_ can be made to go.

Comment: For poetry, you should always provide a larger chunk of text.

Comment: @Lambie - you mean, the author should have done that in the _title_ of the book?  Because I think it is clear (by omission) that the OP didn't _know_ of the poem _in the book_.

Comment: Gosh, you guys here are tough graders.  It wasn't a stupid question, and it's not a crime or sign of negligence to be puzzled about a book title you may have seen in a bookstore or library or somewhere but haven't read.  This isn't the scifi stack - there you _might_ have been expected to read the book.  And what was the question except something appropriate for EL&L? OP apparently thought titles needed to be grammatically correct, now he has answers explaining they _don't_ have to be.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: @davidbak Titles "grammatically correct"? I have no idea what that can even mean!! Crazies.

Comment: It's a sentence fragment. Titles needn't be sentences. What do you mean "grammatically correct" for an arbitrary fragment/title?

Comment: Titles needn't me a full utterance, they have their own logic. In any case, grammar-wise, it's actually appositional even though there is not comma.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's been so much activity on this question and nobody's been able to find an existing rhetoric term derived from Greek for this figure of speech, an omission of a verb in a phrase that follows other phrases with the same verb.  I was expecting somebody to come up with something like "anametaverbaphrasis" or something by now.

Answer (score 45):

It makes complete sense. You're under-citing. Here's the entire verse from [*The Stars My Destination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination):

> Gully Foyle is my name
> And Terra is my nation.
> Deep space is my dwelling place,
> **The stars my destination**.

Just like in "Dogs are my friends, cats my enemies" and "I went to Harvard, my brother to Yale", there is nothing ungrammatical about leaving out a later duplicate verb. Moreover, it is more elegant this way.

But anyway, here clearly the copula is omitted *metri causa*. It would not scan otherwise.

Comment: Worth reading - and several of Bester's other novels are totally top-tier science fiction as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, tchrist. I understand the sentence in context of the entire verse now, but I suppose I was more concerned about the title itself, assuming having not read the verse at all.

Comment: @quincy I think the issue is that titles and sentences aren’t held to the same standards. In fact, it’s uncommon for a title to be a sentence! I think that a reader seeing this title, unfamiliar with the verse, will guess that it’s a fragment, chosen to sound poetic, probably of significance to/explained in the book, and reflecting something about the story (e.g. stars + destination = space travel).

Comment: The verse is based on an "identification verse" that people used to write in books that they owned. Compare with:

"Nathaniel Ager is my name
And England is my nation
Seaburgh is my dwelling place
and Christ is my salvation"

from a diary in "A Warning To The Curious" by M. R. James

Comment: @quincy When a title is an excerpt of some other work, it's often difficult to understand it without knowing that context. Consider Asimov's "The Gods Themselves" or Star Trek's "Whom Gods Destroy". These are meaningless fragments that only make sense if you know the full sentences that they refer to (google them if you want to know).